# Calling function from list of pointers?

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, sdl

I have a list of pointers declared like so :
`std::list < GameObj* > gameObjList;`

The list is supposed to contain pointers to all the objects currently involved in my game.

However, in my main loop, i have this:

```
///Game logic
for (GameObj* o : gameObjList) {
    (*o).step();
}
```

By adding std::cout functions in strategic places, i realised that the loop is executed once per step, which is okay because i only have one such GameObj created and added to the list. However the std::cout's inside the step() function are apparently not reached.

Here's the step() function of PlayerObj:

```
void step() {
    std::cout << " a ";
    int _x = 0, _y = 0;
    _x += keys[SDL_SCANCODE_D];
    _x -= keys[SDL_SCANCODE_A];
    _y += keys[SDL_SCANCODE_S];
    _y -= keys[SDL_SCANCODE_W];
    if (_x == 0 && _y == 0)
        setSpeed(0);
    else setSpeed(1);
    setDir(atan2(_y, _x));
    GameObj::step();
}
```

The last statement, GameObj::step() calls the step function of PlayerObj's parent class, GameObj.

Comment: As for your problem, remember that output through `std::cout` is *buffered*. If you want the output to actually be printed you need to explicitly flush it (either with [`std::flush`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/flush) or with [`std::endl`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl)). I also recommend you learn how to use a debugger to step through your code, line by line.

Comment: Do you explicitly call the PlayerObj's step function? I reckon you just call the step of the parent class and not the child.

Comment: If that's the issue, then why is it working outside of the step function?

Comment: Is `step` `virtual` in `GameObj` ?

Comment: Is `step` virtual? please provide a [mcve].

Comment: No, step is not virtual. I was worried not to overdo it if i post the entire code. Also, @qwn, by my (*o).step() call shouldn't the call to the object stored, and not it's parent, to be called?

Comment: @Diliglont If the function is not virtual in the parent, C++ chooses a function based on the type of the pointer. If the function is virtual in the parent, C++ calls a function based on the actual type of the object. This is exactly what virtual functions are for.

Comment: Okay, it seems i need to read about the "virtual" keyword, i honestly never knew it existed. Will try to make changes based on this, thank you.